# Software product page that references multiple download locations consolidate into one button or provide separate buttons

Tags: usability, layout, content

With Software needing to be made available in many kinds of stores or download locations. When developing a product page, which offers a better user experience for obtaining the software product:

**1. Provide one simple button, that reveals a page of links offering various options.**

**2. Just provide all the links to obtain the product right on the product page itself.**

[image: product download flows, 1 button expanding vs listing all the links on one page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upfront is what it should be. A user will be confident enough to download a software when it is present on the page where other details are buy yes it has to be designed in a way so that it gets attention and indulges the user to download the software.

When a person comes to the product page and he sees every details about the software don't make him click again to get to a page to download... you might loose a user in that phase. Give him a option to download it asap so that he gets the feel of the software while reading about its merits and advantages.

In my designs where we have downloadable content and downloading such content gives us the chance to make prospective clients, I make it in a way that it is always available. I do it by making it sticky to some place or by making it in a floating div.

I interviewed some user and they say, that they felt like getting the software while they were seeing the feature and some said that they wanted that the moment they saw a feature in the video. This is the phase which I call a "SOFT POINT". This is where we have a place to sell it. Don't waste this momentary gap and don't let the user indulge in some activity. Let him get the software as soon as he is willing to get it.

"Bang" that gives us a Selling point.

**I will go with Version 2 but with some modification so that the download option is always visible and available no matter how much i scroll.**